# cURL with -F Option into NodeJS with Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, request, twilio

I'm attempting to convert this CURL command

```
curl -X POST "https://serverless-upload.twilio.com/v1/Services/ZS5798711f7bee1284df67427071418d0b/Assets/ZH4912f44da25f4b1a1c042a16a17f2eac/Versions" \
      -F Content=@./mapping/mapping.json; type=application/json \
      -F Path=mapping.json \
      -F Visibility=private \
      -u username:password
```

into a post request using the package axios,

I've tried

```
    url = `https://serverless-upload.twilio.com/v1/Services/${service_uid}/Assets/${asset_uid}/Versions`

    data = {
        'Path': 'mapping.json',
        'Visibility': 'private',
        'Content': JSON.stringify(mapping),
        'filename': 'mapping.json',
        'contentType': 'application/json'
    }

    await axios.post(url, data,  {
        auth : {
            user: `${accountSid}:${authToken}`
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        }
      }).then((r) => console.log(r));
```

but I'm unsure if this is malformed or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Twilio Node library](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/) actually uses axios under the hood, you can see it in action in the [RequestClient](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/main/lib/base/RequestClient.js). We also have a stand-alone [Serverless API client](https://github.com/twilio-labs/serverless-toolkit/tree/main/packages/serverless-api) which is part of the [Twilio Serverless Toolkit](https://github.com/twilio-labs/serverless-toolkit/) you can use, but it is written with `got` instead.

You can use the [Serverless API](https://github.com/twilio-labs/serverless-toolkit/tree/main/packages/serverless-api) module to save yourself the work of recreating this request.

If you decide to continue with axios, here are  the changes you should make.

#### Auth

Authorization is done via the `Authorization` header, passing a base 64 encoded string made up of the account Sid and auth token.

```js
headers: {
  Authorization: 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(`${accountSid}:${authToken}`).toString('base64')
}
```

#### Data

When uploading an asset, it is done as multipart form data. To build up multipart data in Node.js you can use the [form-data module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data). Something like this should work:

```js
const FormData = require("form-data");

const form = new FormData();
form.append("Path", "mapping.json");
form.append("Visibility", "private");
form.append("Content", JSON.stringify(mapping));
form.append("filename", "mapping.json");
form.append("contentType", "application/json");

await axios.post(url, form,  {
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(`${accountSid}:${authToken}`).toString('base64'), 
    ...form.getHeaders(),
  },
}).then((r) => console.log(r));
```

Let me know how you get on with that.

Comment: you are an absolute godsend. When it comes to doing the same but with a functions upload of a JS file. Is it the same but with
    form.append("Path", "collect");
    form.append("Visibility", "public");
    form.append("Content", data);
    form.append("filename", "collect.js");
    form.append("contentType", "application/javascript");
instead?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is take a JS file in text format from pastebin and upload it to Twilio but doing await axios.get(COLLECT_URL).then((r) =>  data = r.data) and adding to the form form.append("Content", data); but I don't think it works.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I'm afraid. It might be easier if you start a new question with as much context as possible, including any errors, and then let me know and I'll try to answer.

Comment: I've made a new post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66136211/curl-into-nodejs-with-axios-using-hosted-file
Thanks for the help! :)