# cURL into NodeJS with Axios using hosted file

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, request, twilio

I'm trying to convert this cURL command into a request with AXIOS

```
`curl -X POST "https://serverless-upload.twilio.com/v1/Services/${service_uid}/Functions/${function_uid}/Versions" \
    -F "Content=@./template_scripts/collect.js; type=application/javascript" \
    -F "Path=collect.js" \
    -F "Visibility=public" \
    -u "${client.accountSid}:${client.password}"`
```

my attempt at doing so looks like this:

```
    collect_file = ""
    await axios.get("https://pastebin.com/raw/RFYs4n2p").then((r) =>  collect_file = r.data)

    url = `https://serverless-upload.twilio.com/v1/Services/${service_uid}/Functions/${function_uid}/Versions`

    form = new FormData();
    form.append("Path", "collect");
    form.append("Visibility", "public");
    form.append("Content", collect_file);
    form.append("filename", "collect.js");
    form.append("contentType", "application/javascript");

    await axios.post(url, form,  {
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(`${accountSid}:${authToken}`).toString('base64'), 
        ...form.getHeaders(),
    },
    })
```

When filling the "Content" param I'm using the text representation of a JS file that I have hosted on Pastebin. In the initial cURL command you see I specify the file `./template_scripts/collect.js` I don't want to use fs to load the "collect.js" file as I want the code to not use the file system.

The error I get is

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
{
  message: 'Invalid function version content.',
  code: 20001,
  user_error: true,
  http_status_code: 400,
  params: {}
}
400
{
  date: 'Wed, 10 Feb 2021 13:39:08 GMT',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'content-length': '113',
  connection: 'close',
  't-request-id': 'RQ1bf727ce267b5b974cd1eeab122ad02e',
  'x-shenanigans': 'none',
  'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
  'access-control-allow-headers': 'Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Unmodified-Since',
  'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS',
  'access-control-expose-headers': 'ETag',
  'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
  'x-powered-by': 'AT-5000',
  'x-home-region': 'us1',
  'x-api-domain': 'serverless-upload.twilio.com',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000'
}
```

I'm assuming the problem may be with using the text version of the JS file but not entirely sure. When read from pastebin it is returned as type "string".

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the filename as the third argument for "Content" param

```
form.append("Content", collect_file, "collect.js");
```